# Google Bigquery says "Response too large to return" with simple select

Tags: google-bigquery

Modifier *allowLargeResults* is set on and I have also tried interactive and batch query priority.
There are 70M records in table *search_results*, 10M records in *searches* and about (just) 900 in *buy* table. And also the WHERE reduces the number of rows pretty well.

```
SELECT
    s.flyFrom, s.to, s.typeFlight, r.price, b.price, b.affily
FROM [sptest.buy] AS b
INNER JOIN [sptest.search_results] AS r
ON b.booking_token=r.booking_token
INNER JOIN [sptest.searches] AS s
ON s.searchid=r.searchid
WHERE
    DATE(r.saved_at) >= DATE('2015-06-23 00:00:00') AND 
    DATE(s.saved_at) >= DATE('2015-06-23 00:00:00')
LIMIT 10
```

Could the problem be caused by large joining keys?  The *booking_token* key is variable size 50-600 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do couple modifications to this query:

1. Move WHERE clause filters closer to the table scan
2. Use JOIN EACH construct

`SELECT
    s.flyFrom, s.to, s.typeFlight, r.price, b.price, b.affily
FROM [sptest.buy] AS b
INNER JOIN EACH 
  (SELECT * FROM [sptest.search_results] WHERE saved_at > DATE('2015-06-23 00:00:00')) AS r
ON b.booking_token=r.booking_token
INNER JOIN EACH 
  (SELECT * FROM [sptest.searches] WHERE saved_at > DATE('2015-06-23 00:00:00') AS s
ON s.searchid=r.searchid
LIMIT 10`

Comment: Thanks! It works: "8.3s elapsed, 61.8 GB processed". I didn't know that these subqueries are allowed in Bigquery.

Comment: The JOIN EACH construct is interesting to me. My understanding is that it's used to hint to the query optimizer that we're dealing with big tables. Seems like the optimizer should already know how big the tables are, and handle it internally?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is a hint, and in simple cases optimizer should know the sizes, but when join happens over subqueries - it may make mistake in cardinality estimate. The good news is that we are (slowly) rolling out more dynamic join algorithm which will make EACH hint not needed ever, but in the meantime it can help.